# Which versions of MySQL are affected by scalability issues when using MySQL-defined hidden ROW_ID column as PK?

Tags: mysql, primary-key, scalability

When using MySQL with InnoDB storage, having tables without an explicit primary key (PK) and without unique indexes causes a hidden ROW_ID column to be added to those tables to introduce an implicit PK (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-index-types.html). However, I have read that having implicit PKs implies scalability issues due to (1) a global sequence counter for ROW_ID values and (2) the need to lock on dict_sys->mutex for incrementing the counter. Please refer to these pages for more details:

http://blog.jcole.us/2013/05/02/how-does-innodb-behave-without-a-primary-key/

https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/10/18/innodb-scalability-issues-tables-without-primary-keys/

Do these limitations apply to all versions of MySQL? If not, which versions of MySQL are not relying on a global counter (instead of one per table) and a highly demanded mutex for implementing the hidden ROW_ID columns?

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, **all** of them.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to look at the source code of MySQL 5.6 and 5.7 myself, and I found that even the latest MySQL 5.7 still have the limitations of the 'default PK' that I described in my question:

MySQL 5.6:
Relevant file:  https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/5.6/storage/innobase/dict/dict0boot.cc

MySQL 5.7: 
Relevant file: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/5.7/storage/innobase/dict/dict0boot.cc

Relevant code snippet in both cases:

```
void
dict_hdr_flush_row_id(void)
/*=======================*/
{
    dict_hdr_t* dict_hdr;
    row_id_t    id;
    mtr_t       mtr;

    ut_ad(mutex_own(&(dict_sys->mutex)));

    id = dict_sys->row_id;

    mtr_start(&mtr);

    dict_hdr = dict_hdr_get(&mtr);

    mlog_write_ull(dict_hdr + DICT_HDR_ROW_ID, id, &mtr);

    mtr_commit(&mtr);
}
```